# vb.net... What am i doing wrong working with access

Tags: vb.net, syntax

My probelm is at da.Update(dt). I recieve OleDbException was unhandled. Syntax error in INSERT INTO statement. The weird thing is it ran before when I was only saving 10 items and now it doesn't run at all quite confused. Thanks for any assistance.

```
Dim dt As New DataTable
    Dim ds As New DataSet

    con.ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source= C:\MyComplete.accdb;Persist Security Info=False;"

    con.Open()
    MsgBox("here")
    ds.Tables.Add(dt)

    Dim da As New OleDbDataAdapter

    da = New OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM DealerReview", con)

    da.Fill(dt)


    Dim newRow As DataRow = dt.NewRow

    newRow.Item(1) = User
    newRow.Item(2) = Associate
    newRow.Item(3) = "1"
    newRow.Item(4) = Time
    newRow.Item(5) = Hold
    newRow.Item(6) = GreetingR
    newRow.Item(7) = GreetingA
    newRow.Item(8) = GreetingO
    newRow.Item(9) = GreetingTs
    newRow.Item(10) = GreetingG
    newRow.Item(11) = holdUpdate
    newRow.Item(12) = LookupSize
    newRow.Item(13) = DlyD
    newRow.Item(14) = SiPrice
    newRow.Item(15) = SiDoorPrice
    newRow.Item(16) = TBrand
    newRow.Item(17) = TModel
    newRow.Item(18) = SeveralChoices
    newRow.Item(19) = Financing
    newRow.Item(20) = Benefits
    newRow.Item(21) = Apt
    newRow.Item(22) = ITime
    newRow.Item(23) = AssociateScore
    newRow.Item(24) = hms
    newRow.Item(25) = ymd
    newRow.Item(26) = ElapsedTime


    dt.Rows.Add(newRow)
    Dim cb As New OleDbCommandBuilder(da)
    cb.GetInsertCommand()
    da.Update(dt)
    MsgBox("Saved")
    con.Close()
```

Comment: +1: because, as always, asking for help when you need it is a *good* thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the error that you get when your Item's count and/or datatype's do not match the column definitions of the table that you are writing to.  There are other possibilities, but since you mentioned that you added more items, and you have not shown us the table definition, that seems the most likely possibility.

You cannot just add more items (columns) to a database command, they have to match the table columns that you are reading/writing from/to.

Comment: Okay so the columns in access will require the same names as the variable being saved? 
I'm rather new to this so just kind of lost. As it stands this is all the code i have regarding my data base

Comment: If you use names for them, then yes.  But the code you posted is just using their column numbers: Item(1), Item(2), etc.  You need to go into the Access database and look at the definition for the DealerReview table.  That should make things clearer.

Comment: My answer (above) was about matching the number and types of the columns, yes.  In my comment I addressed the names though.

Comment: So if should it be more something like Item(User) or am i changing Item

Comment: It would be Item("User") if you wanted to use the column names.  Then of course, you have to match the column names as well.  Using just the column numbers is fine, but most people feel that using the column names is better for code readability (though it is microscopically slower).

Comment: Alright let me give that a try and see how it goes. Thanks for the help, if i'm still having a issue i'll post back.

Comment: This is getting long (StackOverflow is not good with discussions), so I'd suggest posting a new Question and include the table definition, because that's what your code has to match.