# Vb.net issue updating database

Tags: database, vb.net

My problem occurs at da.Update(dt). I receive an "OleDbException was unhandled, syntax error in INSERT INTO statement" error.  It worked when I used a basic table with no field names and only 10 columns, but now that I have 25 items it doesn't work.

```
Dim dt As New DataTable
    Dim ds As New DataSet

    con.ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source= C:\TPComplete.accdb;Persist Security Info=False;"

    con.Open()
    MsgBox("here")
    ds.Tables.Add(dt)

    Dim da As New OleDbDataAdapter

    da = New OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM DReview", con)

    da.Fill(dt)



    Dim newRow As DataRow = dt.NewRow

    newRow.Item("Caller") = Caller
    newRow.Item("Associate Name") = Associate
    newRow.Item("Store Number") = "1"
    newRow.Item("Number of Rings") = Ring
    newRow.Item("Time on Hold") = HoldTime
    newRow.Item("Greeting: 3 or fewer rings") = GreetingRings
    newRow.Item("Greeting: Asked for your name") = GreetingAskName
    newRow.Item("Greeting: Offered his/her name") = GreetingOfferedName
    newRow.Item("Greeting: Mentioned TIRE PROS in the greeting") = GreetingTirePros
    newRow.Item("Greeting: Associated acted like they are glad") = GreetingGlad
    newRow.Item("Hold for longer than 1 minute") = holdUpdate
    newRow.Item("Ask for the type of car AND look up the size") = LookupSize
    newRow.Item("Ask appropriate questions about the type of driving") = DailyDriving
    newRow.Item("1st Price Mentioned") = SingleTirePrice
    newRow.Item("1st OTD Price Mentioned") = SingleTireOutDoorPrice
    newRow.Item("Tire Brand") = TireBrand
    newRow.Item("Tire Model") = TireModel
    newRow.Item("Offered several tire choices and prices") = SeveralChoices
    newRow.Item("Did they offer financing options") = Financing
    newRow.Item("Mentioned benefits of the location") = Benefits
    newRow.Item("Appointment") = Appointment
    newRow.Item("How long does it take to put them on") = InstallTime
    newRow.Item("Associate Score") = AssociateScore
    newRow.Item("Time Completed") = hms
    newRow.Item("Completed Date") = ymd



    dt.Rows.Add(newRow)
    Dim cb As New OleDbCommandBuilder(da)
    cb.GetInsertCommand()
    da.Update(dt)
    MsgBox("Saved")
    con.Close()
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [vb.net... What am i doing wrong working with access](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11760663/vb-net-what-am-i-doing-wrong-working-with-access)

Comment: It's hard to say without seeing your table definition. It could be any number of things, e.g. `ymd` isn't a date, `Store Number` isn't a string, you've tried to assign to an Identity Column... I'm just guessing until we can see the table.

Comment: @LarsTech: It is not a duplicate of that question, it is a follow-up.

Comment: I was recommended to start a new question.

Comment: How do i get a table definition? Also most things here are strings. Or a bool. ymd is part of the Now() same with hms and I have both outputting

Comment: @Jbailey01: To get the table definition, open your Access DB, then open the DReview table in design mode.  Select the displayed grid of columns and properties and copy it, then paste it into your question here.  I'll format it for you after you do that.

Answer (score 0):

The error "Syntax error in INSERT INTO statement" probably means that the problem is that the OleDb command builder cannot correctly handle the column names that you are using.  These lines:

```
    newRow.Item("Store Number") = "1"
    newRow.Item("Number of Rings") = Ring
    newRow.Item("Time on Hold") = HoldTime
    newRow.Item("Greeting: 3 or fewer rings") = GreetingRings
    newRow.Item("Greeting: Asked for your name") = GreetingAskName
    newRow.Item("Greeting: Offered his/her name") = GreetingOfferedName
    newRow.Item("Greeting: Mentioned TIRE PROS in the greeting") = GreetingTirePros
    newRow.Item("Greeting: Associated acted like they are glad") = GreetingGlad
```

Show that you have "non-variable-type" column names, which is basically any type of name that you could not also use as a variable name.  That is only { A-Z, 0-9 and "_" }.  Non-variable-type names with things like spaces in them are not invalid, but they have to be specially quoted, like this:

```
    newRow.Item("[Store Number]") = "1"
```

Unfortunately, some connection providers (and I think that OleDb is one of them in this case), cannot handle that and will *unquote* them for you, causing the resulting SQL command to be invalid.

The simplest solution is to go back to the column numbers instead of the names (probably why they had that originally).  Alternatively, you could rename all of your column names to remove all of the non-variable-type characters (spaces, colons, etc.).

Comment: Alright. Well what I have been doing is going through and commenting out most of it and storing into a new database and adding to columns to access and two new variables and seeing where failure happens. Right now, now errors yet.